# MYSQL: Get result twice based on if statement

Tags: mysql, if-statement, count

i'm trying to get from each department from the dept table, the number of rich AND poor employees from the employee table.
So far I was able to get one of each but can't seem to figure how to get both rich and poor written on two rows for each dept.

```html
SELECT Depts.Department, IF (Employees.Salary>100000, 'Rich', 'Poor'), 
COUNT(*)  FROM `Employees`, `Depts` 
WHERE Depts.Dept = Employees.Dept 
GROUP BY Depts.Department
```

thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

including your IF logic in GROUP BY

```
SELECT Depts.Department, IF (Employees.Salary>100000, 'Rich', 'Poor'), 
COUNT(*)  FROM `Employees`, `Depts` 
WHERE Depts.Dept = Employees.Dept 
GROUP BY Depts.Department, IF (Employees.Salary>100000, 'Rich', 'Poor')
```

Comment: worked perfectly! I just edited it to get it clearer:
SELECT Depts.Department, IF (Employees.Salary>100000, 'Rich', 'Poor') AS Status, 
COUNT(*)  FROM `Employees`, `Depts` 
WHERE Depts.Dept = Employees.Dept 
GROUP BY Depts.Department, Status

Answer (score 2):

The most legible way to do this would be to union the results;

```
SELECT Depts.Department, 'Poor', COUNT(*)
FROM `Employees`, `Depts`
WHERE Depts.Dept = Employees.Dept AND Employees.Salary <= 100000
GROUP BY Depts.Department

UNION

SELECT Depts.Department, 'Rich', COUNT(*)
FROM `Employees`, `Depts`
WHERE Depts.Dept = Employees.Dept AND Employees.Salary > 100000,
GROUP BY Depts.Department
```